# cannot delete dynamoDB record containing special characters

Tags: ruby, utf-8, amazon-dynamodb, special-characters

I have some dynamoDB record that I just could not delete, and I noticed that those records that had issues all contain special characters. I wrote a small piece of test code, and was able to repeat the issue:

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'
require 'aws-record'

class Task
    include Aws::Record  
    set_table_name "blah"

    string_attr :customer_id, hash_key: true
    string_attr :item, range_key: true
    string_attr :operation, default_value: '+'
    string_attr :device, default_value: 'office-pc'
    string_attr :time, default_value: "00" + Time.now.to_i.to_s
    string_attr :quantity, default_value: '1'
end

Aws.config.update(
    {
        region: 'us-west-2',
        credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
            'foo', 
            'bar'
        ),
        ssl_verify_peer: false
    }
)

#insert two rows
task1 = Task.new(customer_id: "a", item: "\u2713")
task1.save()
task2 = Task.new(customer_id: "a", item: "check")
task2.save()

#query and delete both
resp = Task.query({
    key_conditions: {
        "customer_id" => {
            attribute_value_list: ["a"], 
            comparison_operator: "EQ", 
        }
    }
})
resp.each do 
    |task|
    puts task.item
    task.delete!
end

#query again, to see what's left
resp = Task.query({
    key_conditions: {
        "customer_id" => {
            attribute_value_list: ["a"], 
            comparison_operator: "EQ", 
        }
    }
})
resp.each do 
    |task|
    puts task.item
end
```

Below is the output, as you can see, first two lines show what got inserted, and last row shows that \u2713 is still there even after deletion.

```
check
Ô£ô
Ô£ô
```

gem versions: aws-sdk-core: 2.6.49, aws-sdk-resources: 2.6.49, aws-record: 1.0.3. All of them are the latest versions. ruby is 2.3.1 on windows.

Comment: What response is coming?

Comment: Can you check deleting from console?

Comment: Yes, I was just saying because if you are able to delete from console, then it might be something wrong with code or sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resides in the sdk gem: aws-sdk-core-2.7.0 (2.6.49 was the latest when the OP was posted, 2.7.0 is the latest now). It can be easily fixed with an one-line change in lib\aws-sdk-core\json\handler.rb.

Below is the change:

```
def parse_body(context)
    if simple_json?(context)
        Json.load(context.http_response.body_contents)
    else
        rules = context.operation.output
        json = context.http_response.body_contents.bytes.pack('c*').force_encoding('utf-8')
        #below line is the original code
        #json = context.http_response.body_contents
        Parser.new(rules).parse(json == '' ? '{}' : json)
    end
end
```